# Do dollars reach MtGox through other channels than Dwolla?

Tags: mtgox, wire-transfers

There've been some questions here about MtGox getting dollars through Dwolla, but what about other channels besides Dwolla?  Are dollars still reaching MtGox somehow?  The price of BTC on MtGox a few minutes ago was over $131, up a bit from a few days ago.  There must be dollars there for people to bid with, and buy bitcoins with; otherwise this couldn't happen.

Another thing I've wondered about is transferring dollars straight to a bank account in the USA.  International bank account numbers are not used in the United States.  Is there a way to do it without one of those?

Comment: Mtgox is in Japan, and they accept wire transfers and other methods. I think Dwolla was being used to reduce the fees, but it was a US-only thing.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can transfer cash to Mt.Gox using a service like BitInstant.

Comment: Only BitInstant?

Comment: This answer really needs some more details on how this is done, even if just at a high level.

Comment: You can do this by visting bitinstant.com, choose Dwolla as your pay from acct.  Then, choose Mt.Gox as your pay to acct.  All instructions regarding how to finish this transaction will be provided as you use the website and go thru the steps to do this transaction.